# How to define relative touch size in custom view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-touch-event

I do a custom view that builds a sound wave. It consists of drawn columns. I also have slide bars to indicate what to crop, they are also represented by painted columns. The problem is that at a certain level of scale, when I want to move one of the columns with a click, I don’t hit it. Is there any way to set the optimal width of the touch area to solve this problem?

Here I can catch slide bar:

[image: Screenshot catch slide bar]

But in this case I can't:

[image: Screenshot catch slidebar not working]

Also I can't make the click area too wide because it is used the rest of the columns to handle different touch events.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1025634/Множество-кнопок-в-custom-view/1025820

Comment: @Style-7, wrong

Comment: Man I do not understand your problem. Custom view can not build a sound wave, You have full control, just use variables.

Comment: @Style-7 Bruh, I know it) I just want to determine touch square 
which will depend on the zoom level

Answer (score 0):

You should not check against each column for a touch event it is not a good way I think. You should determine the time point by using touch event. The procedure is like that you get y value of the touch event then you calculates the start and end of the sound block at the screen touch event occurs. After that you can determine the time point of the corresponding block then you search for that time point in your data structure. I think you should optimize your data structure for such calculation. Example calculation, screen width is 1000px, the start of the screen corresponds 2:30 and the end of the screen corresponds 4:00 and a touch event occurred at (400,600). TheTouchTimePoint = 150s + 90*(600/100). Then by using the touchtimepoint you can find the corresponding sound column.